# Trying to set custom BackgroundView to a UITableView with searchDisplayController causing message sent to deallocated instance

Tags: ios, crash, tableview, uisearchdisplaycontroller

I have an `UITableViewController` backed by a `NSFetchedResultsController`. 
Whenever the tableview is empty I am trying to set a custom backgroundview loaded from a NIB.

```
- (NSInteger) numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {

    NSInteger numberOfSections = [super numberOfSectionsInTableView:tableView];

    if (tableView != self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView) {

        if (numberOfSections == 0 ||
            (numberOfSections == 1 && [super tableView:tableView numberOfRowsInSection:0] == 0))
            [tableView setBackgroundView:[self viewForEmptyTable]];
        else
            [tableView setBackgroundView:nil];
   }
    return numberOfSections;
}

- (TableViewEmptyBGView*) viewForEmptyTable {

    if (_viewForEmptyTable == nil) {
        NSArray* viewForEmptyTableNIB = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"iPhone-ViewForEmptyTable"
                                                                      owner:nil
                                                                    options:nil];

        _viewForEmptyTable = [viewForEmptyTableNIB firstObject];
        [_viewForEmptyTable setHeader:self.listaVaziaHeaderText];
        [_viewForEmptyTable setBody:self.listaVaziaBodyText];
    }

    return _viewForEmptyTable;
}
```

Screenshots: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/628444/Crash-Screenshots.png

I've been trying to find uselessly someone that had similar issue before as I am stuck on this for days.
If the tableview is loaded empty it's fine (1), however if the fetchedresultcontroller (2)  includes a cell (3) and removes that after (4) the app crashes (5) with:
`*** -[UIView isHidden]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xc6cf440`

It seems to be something related to the `UISearchDisplayController` trying to send a message to a deallocated object:

```
#   Event Type  ∆ RefCt RefCt   Timestamp   Responsible Library Responsible Caller
    Malloc/Retain/Release (8)           00:09.546.357   UIKit   -[UITableView setTableHeaderBackgroundColor:]
0    Malloc +1  1   00:09.546.357   UIKit   -[UITableView setTableHeaderBackgroundColor:]
1    Retain +1  2   00:09.546.385   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _addSubview:positioned:relativeTo:]
2    Retain +1  3   00:09.546.409   UIKit   -[UISearchDisplayController _configureSearchBarForTableView]
3    Retain +1  4   00:09.546.474   UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews]
4    Release    -1  3   00:09.552.790   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _invalidateSubviewCache]
11   Release    -1  2   01:22.884.181   UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) removeFromSuperview]
12   Release    -1  1   01:22.884.182   UIKit   -[UITableView setTableHeaderBackgroundColor:]
13   Release    -1  0   01:22.884.182   UIKit   -[UISearchDisplayController _updateTableHeaderBackgroundViewInTableView:amountScrolledUnder:]
    Retain/Release (6)          00:09.563.097   UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews]
5    Retain +1  4   00:09.563.097   UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews]
6    Retain +1  5   00:09.657.977   UIKit   -[UIView(Hierarchy) subviews]
7    Retain +1  6   00:09.808.482   QuartzCore  -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
8    Release    -1  5   00:09.808.483   QuartzCore  -[CALayer layoutSublayers]
9    Release    -1  4   00:09.821.299   QuartzCore  CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
10   Release    -1  3   01:22.877.290   UIKit   -[UIView(Internal) _invalidateSubviewCache]
14  Zombie      -1  01:22.884.204   UIKit   -[UISearchDisplayController _updateTableHeaderBackgroundViewInTableView:amountScrolledUnder:]
```

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem right now. The code I'm working on used to create a tableview programmatically and when I moved it to IB it started to give me the same error.

Comment: Have a look at my answer below, see if that solves your issue as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that creating a property with strong reference to the emptyView solved the problem of message sent to deallocated instance.

```
@interface ListObjectsCoreDataTVC()
    @property (nonatomic, strong) TableViewEmptyBGView* viewForEmptyTable;
@end
```